# Updating/Changing password of h2 database in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

Currently I'm developing a Java application for a student database using a h2 embedded database. All I want to know is how to update the password with user input.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String username,password,user="admin",pass;
System.out.println("User name:");
username=sc.next();
System.out.println("Password:");
password=sc.next();
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection   c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:database",username ,password);
Statement s=c.createStatement();
System.out.println("Enter new password:");
pass=sc.next();
s.execute("alter user "+user+" identified by "+pass);
```

Given above is the partial snippet which shows the following error on execution:

> Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER USER ADMIN IDENTIFIED[*] BY POPPER "; expected "SET, RENAME, ADMIN"; SQL statement:
>   alter user admin identified by popper [42001-176]

Comment: Did you read the fancy manual? http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_user_set_password You might also want to use prepared statement or *escape* user and pass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tried Oracle syntax. Try the h2 syntax

```
ALTER USER admin SET PASSWORD 'aaa';
```

See http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_user_set_password for more details

**EDIT 1**

You code needs to be changed to

```
s.execute("alter user "+user+" set password '"+pass + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
s.execute("alter user "+user+" set password "+pass);
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "POPPERY" not found; this error occurs on using your query